# How to call the UICollectionView built in swipe gesture from a Pan Gesture on the view? (preferable in swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipangesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I apologize in advance if this question has been answered somewhere else, I've tried finding it, but no luck.

I have a UICollectionView taking up half my view with each cell taking up the full width of the view. It scrolls perfectly and changes images just fine when I swipe across the cells.

I'd like to add a gesture to the entire view so that even if I swipe below the UICollectionView say on top of a view or a label, that the scroll will still take place and the built in functionality like func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) will also be called.

Is there a way to call the same built in UICollectionView Swipe Gesture that get's called when you swipe over the UICollectionView(Cells)

I've tried multiple variations of the following:

```
var colView = UICollectionView!
var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.init(target: colView, action: Selector("handleSwipe:"))
var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.init(target: colView, action: Selector("handleSwipe:"))

swipeRight.direction = .Right
swipeLeft.direction = .Left

view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
```

I've tried printing out the UICollectionView Gesture Recognizers, but either haven't interpreted them correctly or am missing something

```
Optional([<UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer: 0x7fec88c9df40; state = Possible; delaysTouchesBegan = YES; view = <UICollectionView 0x7fec890a2200>; 
target= <(action=delayed:, target=<UICollectionView 0x7fec890a2200>)>>, <UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer: 0x7fec88c9e8d0; state = Possible; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <UICollectionView 0x7fec890a2200>; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=<UICollectionView 0x7fec890a2200>)>; must-fail = 
 {
    <UIScrollViewPagingSwipeGestureRecognizer: 0x7fec88c995d0; state = Possible; view = <UICollectionView 0x7fec890a2200>; target= <(action=_handleSwipe:, target=<UICollectionView 0x7fec890a2200>)>>
}>, 
<UIScrollViewPagingSwipeGestureRecognizer: 0x7fec88c995d0; state = Possible; view = <UICollectionView 0x7fec890a2200>; target= <(action=_handleSwipe:, target=<UICollectionView 0x7fec890a2200>)>; must-fail-for = 
{
    <UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer: 0x7fec88c9e8d0; state = Possible; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <UICollectionView 0x7fec890a2200>; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=<UICollectionView 0x7fec890a2200>)>>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with it but you're adding the collection view as a target then adding the gesture recognizers to the main view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a collectionview respond to pan gestures outside of it's own view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595705/how-to-make-a-collectionview-respond-to-pan-gestures-outside-of-its-own-view)

Comment: you should use touchesBegan on your viewcontroller and pass it to you collectionview, answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595705/how-to-make-a-collectionview-respond-to-pan-gestures-outside-of-its-own-view