# UICollectionView scroll outside it's view

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview

I want to scroll my collection view on scroll of outside view...
I found this answer: [How to make a collectionview respond to pan gestures outside of it's own view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595705/how-to-make-a-collectionview-respond-to-pan-gestures-outside-of-its-own-view) but it doesn't works on me.

Code in my viewController

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    pager.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    pager.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
    pager.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    pager.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pager = Carousel(withFrame: self.view.bounds, andInsets: 5)
    pager.dataSource = self
    pager.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pager.register(MyCollectionView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    self.swipeView.addSubview(pager)
    pager.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
    pager.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    pager.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    pager.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
}
```

Help please, thanks

Comment: what is your problem? is there an error?

Comment: The problem is: my collection view doesn't scroll it's content :( no any errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell your view `Carousel` in your case that the touch is inside the view

You need to override the `hitTest` function and return self *carousel*

```
class TouchCarousel: Carousel {
   override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
      return true
   }
}
```

then use the class that you created

```
pager = TouchCarousel(withFrame: self.view.bounds, andInsets: 5)
```

Comment: @Giraffe i just updated my answer to enable clicks on cells or items inside the Carousel

Comment: Got it) Thanks for that a lot) It's very important for me :)

Comment: what is Carousel, how can I make it with a normal UICollectionview

Comment: @PabloMartinez carousel is UICollectionView :)